# Detect information about active SharePoint-shared Word document from VSTO add-in

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, vsto

There is a Word document on SharePoint. A user has it open in the desktop Word app, which has a VSTO add-in installed.
Is it possible to detect any of the following from the VSTO add-in?:

- The path of the active file on SharePoint
- Whether there is an active connection to the SharePoint server, or if the user is working
  offline
- Whether the document is up-to-date or if there is a merge operation pending/in progress

It looks like you can determine whether the file is on SharePoint by checking the DocumentLibraryVersions property of the document.